# How to mock FluentValidation ValidationResults in test

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking, fluentvalidation

This is the method that I want to test:

```
public async Task<object> CreateExpense(CreateExpenseCommand command)
{
    var validationResults = await _validator.ValidateAsync(command);
    if (!validationResults.IsValid)
    {
        return validationResults.Errors.First().ToString();
    }
    //more code that is irrelevant for this post
}
```

To test this, I need to mock `_validatior`, which is defined as `private readonly IValidator<CreateExpenseCommand> _validator;` and is used through constructor injection.

I am using AutoFixture with AutoMoqCustomizations and Moq for mocking. Maybe I should use Moq exclusively?

This is what I try to do in the test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CreateExpense_Success()
{
    //Arrange
    var service = _fixture.Fixture.Freeze<Mock<IValidator<CreateExpenseCommand>>>();
    service.Setup(x => x.Validate((CreateExpenseCommand)It.IsAny<IValidator<CreateExpenseCommand>>())).Returns(It.IsAny<ValidationResult>);
    
    //more code that is irrelevant for this post
}
```

However, this results in error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to instance of an object'.

The error is pretty self-explanatory, but I don't know how to mock correctly.

Image of error:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very late to answer what solved it for me, but here goes:

```bash
namespace ExpenseTests.Application
{
    public class CreateExpenseServiceTests
    {
        private TestFixture _fixture;
        public CreateExpenseServiceTests()
        {
            _fixture = new TestFixture();
        }
        [Fact]
        public async Task CreateExpense_Success()
        {
            //Arrange
            var expense = _fixture.Fixture.Create<Expense>();
            CreateExpenseCommand command = _fixture.Fixture.Build<CreateExpenseCommand>()
                .With(c => c.ExpenseCategory, "HOTEL").Create();
            var validationResults = _fixture.Fixture.Create<ValidationResult>();

            var addMock = new Mock<ICreateExpense>();
            addMock.Setup(x => x.CreateExpense(command)).ReturnsAsync(expense);
            ICreateExpense addService = addMock.Object;

            var validatorMock = new Mock<IValidator<CreateExpenseCommand>>();
            validatorMock.Setup(x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<CreateExpenseCommand>())).Returns(validationResults);

            //Act
            var response = await addService.CreateExpense(command);

            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(typeof(Expense), response.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of it is domain code that you can ignore. Let me know if you have further questions - hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, such a great answer! it helped me a lot @thesystem .

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an object when doing the setup:

```
service.Setup(x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<IValidator<CreateExpenseCommand>>()))
    .Returns(<*1>);
```

*1 - Here return the object that you wish to be returned when you call `ValidateAsync` function. Don't do `It.IsAny` as it returns null which causes the `NullReferenceException`.

Also, you need to add `virtual` to the `ValidateAsync` method in order to let it be overridable.

Comment: Thank you Misha. I have made an validationResult that the setup returns.

However, since I in the actual code use `ValidateAsync`, I need to use that instead of mocking what happens upon `Validate` in test. But when I change to `ValidateAsync` and `ReturnsAsync` it gives me error: ```an expression tree  may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments.``` Any idea?

Comment: I figured it out. I will add an answer that goes more into detail. Thanks for your contribution, it helped me make ends meet at last.

Comment: @thesystem , can you please provide me the solution ? I have the same problem and I can't figure it out

Comment: @Wahéb I havent been logged in for a long time and didn't see your comment until now, sorry! I will try to post a usable answer immediately.